# Python: How to better write the following piece of code?

Tags: python, optimization

I am quite new to python and hence not fully aware of its power. I have the following piece of code which I think should work faster. I have a felling that it can be done using numpy/map but not sure how to construct it.

Both the dictionaries in question here have 10,000 keys with values formed by  list of 7 elements, like:

```
T_com ={0: [[1.2, 3,.65,.63, 3, 3 , 5.5]] 1:[[1.7, 2,.55,.13, 2, 8 , 5.5]] ...10,000th key:[[3.2, 9,.15,.23, 1, 3 , 2.5]]}
```

For this, my current code (discussed below) is stretching into **hours**, which I have a feeling is not good. Basically, I am reading the list associated with each key in both the dictionaries, calculating a score on them then appending the score to a dictionary and finally writing it to ZODB. Following is the snippet (The dictionary `R_com` is exactly similar in structure to `T_com` defined above.):

```
 for tar_node,tar_community in T_com.iteritems():   # iterate over the key value pair of first dic
     for i,(ref_node,ref_community) in enumerate(R_com.iteritems()):  # iterate over second dictionary. Enumeration was required for some other operation
         score = compute_score(T_com[tar_node],R_com[ref_node])      # calculate some score   
         bTree_container.setdefault(tar_node,PersistentList () ).append( [ref_node,score,priority.pop(),0])    #Builds a list of lists associated with every value of tar_node
         if i % 2500 ==0:            # After every 2,500 values temporarily save the data to disk
             transaction.savepoint(True)
 transaction.commit()  # finally write all the data to disk
```

Any suggestions on how to reduce the running time/avoid loops ? In genereal what are the best practices in python to handle such cases ?

As suggested, some results from cProfile:-

```
200000000 3792.449    0.000 3792.449    0.000 {numpy.core.multiarray.array}
100000000   51.033    0.000   51.186    0.000 {method 'setdefault' of 'BTrees.IOBTree.IOBTree' objects}
```

Comment: Possibly belongs on [codeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: You are looping 100,000,000 times - of course it is slow. What does `compute_score` do?

Comment: compute_score is a very simple function, just calculates the dot product of both the vectors, by first converting them to numpy array().

Comment: @R.Bahl, convert them to numpy arrays _before_ you run the loops.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget, sorry but I am relatively new to SE/SO, was not aware of codereview

Comment: It only takes me a few minutes to compute 10^8 dot products of 7-element numpy arrays like this.  You might want to do some profiling: maybe the setdefault line is slow.

Comment: @DSM: Any suggestions for improvement ? I am currently running cProfile to do some profiling of it.

Comment: @DSM, but there are 2*10^8 list->array conversions when there only needs to be 2*10^4. The conversion probably takes longer than the dot product

Comment: @gnibbler: Point noted ! let me implement this. Can you also comment on whether for loop is the way to do it, or there exists better methods in python ?

Comment: @gnibbler: yeah, I'm one of the two upvotes on your comment :^).  It does slow things down enormously to do all the unnecessary conversions -- my 'few minutes' number does it the right way -- but I don't know if that dominates whatever the setdefault line is doing (PersistentList creation, list creation, append, etc.)

Comment: @DSM: The setdefault line is just incrementally building a list for every key in `T_com` using all the scores calculated for it. Do you that it can be optimized ?

Comment: @gnibbler: You were right, cProfile shows that numpy array conversion took time, where the setdefault is quite fast

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it you are creating a tree and a new node for each element in each dictionary that you iterate through.

If you need to examine each element of the dictionary to calculate the score your only other option is the have a secondary resource that contains some computation which would prevent you from having to reiterate through each field.

Similarly you could keep a copy of each dictionary's generated tree and then simply add on to each one as you get more information and ultimately link them all together.

Sorry I would have left this as a comment but I am not allowed to comment or maybe can't figure out how...

Anyway, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
score = compute_score(T_com[tar_node]tar_community,R_com[ref_node]ref_community)
```

this could save you some dict lookup time, but your root problem is x*y; if you really need this, and cares much about running time, consider using cython or pure c code to accelerate

Comment: thought about using C, but currently I am looking for a pythonic method of optimization.

Comment: pinkdawn : can you given some clue on how to possibly convert the above code to Cython ? I have little experience in this domain.

Comment: @R.Bahl check tutorial here: http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/tutorial.html ; cython will auto generate c code for you, and call gcc to compile it, if you can do c, you could also modify the code cython generated

Answer (score 0):

Even if each execution of compute_score takes only 1ms, if you have 10k elements in T_com and 10k elements in R_com this will take you 10k * 10k * 1ms, which is about 27 hours. The way you presented, this is an O(n2) problem. Can you simplify your logic? If you can't, you need other techniques - parallel or distributed execution, for example.

==edit==

As you explained in the comments, this is a dot product. Could you try to reduce it to O(n)? Something like:

```
scores = []
for index in T_com.keys():
    score = T_com[index] * R_com[index]
dot_product = sum(scores)
```

Comment: actually compute_Score is faster than that, takes around 10^-4, so this code take around 3 hours. You can think of the logic as calculating the pair wise dot product of a bunch of vectors stored in two dictionaries and then storing the result on the disk. But I have a feeling there is a better way to write it in python, possibly using numpy for indexing or maps, but not sure how

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I am not exactly sure how this would work, but let me give it a thought.